# Why jquery select.val() returning type:value in an AngularJS environment?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-xnrrot?file=home%2Fhome.html
When I change the dropdown, the value will be shown as number:1.
When I remove ng-model in home.html, the value will be displayed without "number:".
Can you explain that, please?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `ng-model` returns the value with it **data type** . Therefore you are getting `number:1`  when you add `ng-model` 

**For Example**

```
<select id="s1" ng-model="$ctrl.personId">
  <option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.persons" ng-value="option.name">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
<div id="output"></div>
```

In Above example, if you give `ng-value="option.name"` instead of `ng-value="option.id"` then you will get output **string:Alice** . 
This happens because the datatype of name is string. And same when you set `ng-value="option.id"` , it will give you `number:1` because datatype of ID is `number`

Hope you are satisfied with explanation.

Comment: hm, but this has changed since angular js 1.5.8. When I change the version to 1.5.8 in the package.json, it works as expected (without datatype).